# Inserting several rows at the same IndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'd like to insert several rows at once (with one animation) into my `UITableView`.

In order to do so, I added my insertion code within `self.tableView.performBatchUpdates`:

```
tableView.performBatchUpdates({
    for object in objects {
        // my model holds all objects; inserting an object to 
        // the model returns the index path at the insertion position.
        let indexPath = model.insert(object)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
})
```

Then, I get an `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (19) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (10), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (5 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

I think that this error occurs because I specify two IndexPaths twice (19 - 2*2 = 15). Does that make sense? The same IndexPath exists several times in my `indexPaths` array, because I want to add several rows (one after the other) at the same indexPath. 
It seems like I cannot do this.

My problem is that I have another array that contains some objects that I fetch from a database. Every time I receive a new object, I add insert it into my array first, store the insertion index path in a variable and then, I'd like to add the object to my `UITableView`.

Do I have to update my table view for every single object?

My steps:

1. receiving an object from the database
2. calling `performBatchUpdates()`
3. within `performBatchUpdates()`: 
   3.1 inserting the object into an array and getting the insertion index
   3.2 inserting the new row

What I think what happens: 
Let's assume I get back the index 4 at step 3.1. Then I insert the new row. 
Another object arrives, I also get back the index 4. The `UITableView` reloads only in the end of `performBatchUpdates()`, so it'll get the same object twice. Consequently, it throws an error because the datasource functions say there have to be more rows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for indexPath in indexPaths {
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```

you need

```
tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths , with: .none)
```

as when the first insertRows in case 1 runs , the dataSource is being changed for other indexPaths which will lead to this crash

Comment: But the data source will still say that there're 19 rows, but only 15 got inserted, won't it? Because the array holds the same index path twice. I updated my question to make things more clear.

Comment: The idea is that when you use `insertRows` the change in the data source should be addition with a count equal to the count of the array you send to `insertRows` , if you want to insert indexPath by indexPath , then you need to divide the change in the dataSource according to that

Comment: No, the problem persists when trying that.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to keep track of the final array index the one which table view is using it for it's DataSource Delegate such as Number of rows and cellForRowAt indexPath

The Error tries to Explain that your section has more indexPaths than the number of rows in the section. keep in mind to insert all the objects to the array before you try to insert them to the TableViews section.

Note: See if you're appending to the array or inserting to be shower to get the right index number.

As @T.Meyar said
You're calling BatchUpdates but still trying to add single indexPath to the tableView.

```
tableView.performBatchUpdates({
   // removed for loop
   tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
})
```

I think you have to add fallback for BatchUpdates because iOS 10 does not supports BatchUpdates then you have to use for loop as you had before between for loop

```
// Start update
tableView.beginUpdates
for indexPath in indexPaths {
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
// end updates
tableView.endUpdates
```

Comment: What works: `for object in objects { tableView.beginUpdates(); let indexPath = model.insert(object); tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none); tableView.endUpdates(); }`